# kotlin: How to read a Uri in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been stuck with this for almost a week. Triend almost any answer/tutorial I found, but no luck yet.

I have an app that uses the camera. After the user takes a pic, and select the check/OK button in the camera, the camera returns, among other things, the Uri where the image was stored. It cames in the form of: `content://media/external/images/media/122` (this is an actual pic in the phone), if I ask for the Uri.path I'll get in this case: `/external/images/media/123`

Now, with the Uri object, I can assign it to an imageView like `imageView.setImageURI()` and it works, so I'm pretty confident the images are stored *somewhere*.

Now, next thing my app should do, is take all the pictures taken, and send them to an API.

My problem is, when I try to read the Uri with any method, it gives me a `FileNotFound Exception`, no matter if I use the Uri or the path.

So I really don't know what to do. What am I missing? Do I have to explicitly save the image in a working directory? If so, how is it done? If not, how do I get the full path name including the filename? When I look at the DCIM directoy in the phone, I don't find the pics.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Code to take the pic:

```
    btnTomarFoto.setOnClickListener {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
          PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
          ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
        ) {
          // El permiso no fue concedido
          val permission = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
          requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE)
        } else {
          // El permiso ya estaba concedido
          openCamera()
        }
      } else {
        // El SO es menor que Marshmallow
      }
    }
  }
```

Code to open the camera:

```
  private fun openCamera() {
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture")
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From the camera")
    image_uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE)
  }
```

Code to store the Uri into the database:

```
  private fun guardarFoto() {
    var foto = FotografiaModel(actividad_id!!, image_uri.toString(), txtObservacion.text.toString())
    Log.w(tag, "URI: $image_uri PATH: " + image_uri!!.path + " Encoded Path: " + image_uri!!.encodedPath)
    fotografiaDBHelper.insertFoto(foto)
    visitaDBHelper.actualizaEstado(actividad_id!!, "INICIADO")
  }
```

There are some more things the code does, but this is the main thing. To show the received Uri into an Imageview I use:

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      imageView.setImageURI(image_uri)
      Log.v(tag, "Image URI: $image_uri")
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you post you're code what have you tried so far so we can understand your problem perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is, when I try to read the Uri with any method, it gives me a FileNotFound Exception, no matter if I use the Uri or the path.

That is because it is not a file. It is a `Uri`.

For example, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839478/kotlin-how-to-read-a-uri-in-android` is a `Uri`. Your code assumes that the path `/questions/56839478/kotlin-how-to-read-a-uri-in-android` is the only thing that matters in a `Uri`. By your argument, every single computer on the planet (plus those in orbit) have a file located at `/questions/56839478/kotlin-how-to-read-a-uri-in-android`. That is not how a `Uri` works. You need to use the entire `Uri` to determine how to use it. In this case, `https` as a scheme means that you use HTTPS as a protocol to talk to the designated server (`stackoverflow.com`) to retrieve the content.

Similarly, the `content` scheme in your `Uri` from `insert()` indicates that you use `ContentResolver` to work with it. In particular, you can use `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, just as you might use `HttpUrlConnection` or OkHttp to get an `InputStream` on an `https` `Uri`.

In particular, since you delegated data storage to some other app (the `MediaStore`), where the image is stored is up to somebody else, and it is not necessarily on the filesystem in a place where you can access it. That is particularly true on Android Q and higher, where you have limited access to arbitrary locations on the device via filesystem APIs.

> Now, next thing my app should do, is take all the pictures taken, and send them to an API.

I am going to guess that "send them to an API" means "upload them to a server" (versus "call an API exposed by a library on the device" or "call a method in the Android SDK"). In that case, you have some code for talking to that server. It might be general-purpose code (e.g., OkHttp, Retrofit) or API-specific code (e.g., Facebook SDK).

Regardless, you will need to see what that code supports for your image content:

- If it supports a `Uri`, try using your `Uri`
- If it supports `InputStream` (or a `Reader` of some type), use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`
- If it supports a `FileDescriptor` or `AssetFileDescriptor`, use `openFileDescriptor()` on a `ContentResolver`
- If it only supports `File`, instead of using `contentResolver.insert()` to get the `Uri` to send to the camera app, use `FileProvider`, so you can have the images saved in a file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`)
- Etc.

Comment: Oh I see... my first mistake is to asume the URI was a pointer to a physical file, saved by the camera Intent on its own, and looks it is not. So then what is an URI for? --- on other things, the API expects I pass it an image file via POST. What should I do with the image the camera just took?

Comment: @luisfer: "So then what is an URI for?" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier "the API expects I pass it an image file via POST" -- you will need to talk to the Web developers and determine exactly what that means (e.g., is this a base64-encoded byte array of the JPEG bytes?). Then you will need to decide how you are going to communicate with that API (e.g., Retrofit). Then, and only then, will you be in position to start making decisions on what to do with the image that the user took with a camera app.

Comment: I'm the developer of the API. It is expecting a FILE like the ones you pass by POST from a HTML `<input type="file" ...>` form. I'm using Voley which I find quite easy to use, and more than enough for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @luisfer: I have not used Volley for that sort of request, so I cannot provide details on how to use it. Most likely, you will wind up using `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` in one form or another.